# Calling a method in a UserControl from another UserControl

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I've been researching this problem for some time now and I cannot seem to find a solution that works. I want to call a method a UserControl from a method in another UserControl.

In UserControl1 I have a method:

```
public void update(int lineNum, double price)
{
      // do stuff...
           
            
      // then call the method in another UserControl
      UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2();
      uc2.refreshList();
}
```

And in UserControl2, I have a method:

```
public void refreshList()
{
     // do stuff....
}
```

Of course, I have tried other methods of doing this other than simply creating an object of the UserControl and calling the method that way but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe you explain why you want to do this. Possibly this is a XY problem

Comment: Such a tight coupling of user controls is not good. Instead, raise an event in the first user control and let the form hosting the controls call the RefreshList method in the other one.

Comment: Also: `new UserControl2()` will create a new instance of the second control, call refreshList on this new instance and then discard the instance. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @Klamsi I want to do this because I want a tablelayoutpanel to update once when update() is called. The problem is the tablelayourpanel is not in the same user control as UserControl1.

Comment: Still a bit vague. But maybe this helps? There is somebody who calls update(). Ideally this somebody is in a method that exactly describes what is going on. For example "InsertNewPriceItem". And this somebody is responsible that all UserControls do the right things. Not the UserControls by themselves. Keep the UI as dumb as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Having such dependencies between user controls is not good: it limits the use and makes them hardly testable in isolation.

You have several options to achieve what you want.

**Let the caller do the orchestration**

You did not state where the code resides that calls `update`. But since the method is `public`, I assume that this is called from outside `UserControl1`. Maybe it is possible to put the `userControl2.refreshList()` call there just after the call to `userControl1.update()`

**Use an event**

You could define an event in `UserControl1` e.g. `public event EventHandler UpdatePerformed` and raise it at the end of the `update` method. Then in your form, subscribe to this event and call `refreshList` from there:

```
userControl1.UpdatePerformed += (s, e) => userControl2.refreshList();
```

Comment: When you say "in your form" are you saying in the file that contains main? Also, to raise the event in update(), would I so something like `EventHandler handle = UpdatePerformed` then `handle(this, EventArgs.EMPTY)`?

Comment: I meant: your Winforms UI does not show `UserControl`s, it shows `Form`s. And on one of these forms you have added your UserControls, right? Regarding raising the event: yes, but you should check your delegate `handle` for `null` before invoking it.